# Custom rosbag record in launch file (several args)

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

i'm trying to use rosbag record to pass multiple arguments in a launch file, but unfortunately the folder is not created and recordings aren't started.

I used the following arguments:

node pkg ="rosbag" type="record" name="record_run" args="record -o ./rosbags record --split --duration=15m -a" />

**record -o ./rosbags --split --duration=15m -a**

**-o** : timestamp for bag file

**--split --duration=15m** : split the bag when duration is reached

**-a :** record all topics

Does anyone know what i did wrong, i have tried different variations, but it's still not working

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397877/custom-rosbag-record-in-launch-file-(several-args)/) by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2022-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**news**

i have solved the bug. To all those who want to use the launch file:

### <--How to use

### <--add a launch file

<---->

### <--add a node package

<---->

<--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->

**<--1. start Yujin LiDAR node-->**

node pkg ="yujin_yrl_v2_package" type="yrl_pub" name="lidar_run"

**<--start rviz node-->**

node pkg ="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz_run" args="-d /home/pkatsoulakos/catkin_ws/src/launch/settings.rviz"

**<--start rosbag node-->**

node pkg ="rosbag" type="record" name="record_run" args="record -o /home/pkatsoulakos/catkin_ws/src/launch/rosbags/Besprechungsraum/ --split --duration=15m -a"

---

Originally posted by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) with karma: 28 on 2022-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-03-23**:
Just a note: this is not a bug, but likely expected behaviour.

Every executable you start using `roslaunch` has the `CWD` (ie: current working directory) changed to `$HOME/.ros` (at least, on Linux, and if you haven't changed the default).

In your original post, you specified this as the directory for `rosbag` to record to: `./rosbags`. That's a relative path, and would resolve to `$HOME/.ros/rosbags`.

You might want to check whether there are `.bag`s stored in that directory on your system.

Changing the path to an absolute path solves this, as now the `CWD` does not influence where the files will end up.

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-03-23**:
thank you for the advice. In the future I will take care of that